# Stem Error:[Errno:111]

Tags: configuration, error, stem

I am new to stem(not the tree stem, the proxy).
I made a python script that connects to a proxy using stem.
I am getting a [Errno:111] error, how do I fix it?
(The error occurred even though I typed:"service tor start" in the terminal)
(Using Kali Linux)

```
Error:[Errno:111] Connection refused
```

Help will be appreciated a lot. Thank you.

Comment: Can we see more of the error? Errno 111 sounds like "Connection refused". Somewhere, you're connecting to a service that doesn't exist or isn't accepting connections. We need more information, e.g. some code snippet that illustrates what you're trying to do.

Comment: Okay so it is connection refused, but there's still no context in what its being refused to? Can we get the previous requested code snippet?

Comment: It was just that. Error [Errno 111]

Comment: Yes, we need to see the code. There's no way we can tell anything from some random error without any context.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved my answer by typing :

```
/etc/init.d/tor restart
```

in the terminal. Apparently Tor was not restarting properly.